# React-Redux: Access dispatch type in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a login system with React-Redux and I want to display JSX when a specific dispatch Type is send.
For example when the login system failed the dispatch type is `LOGIN_FAIL` and I want to display an error message but when the authentication is successful then the dispatch type is `LOGIN_SUCCESS` and I want to display a success message. I already access the username trough mapStateToProps but I was curious if there is another way trough the dispatch type to do conditional rendering?
Thanks for your advice or tips on that topic.

This is my actions.js:

```
export const login = (email, password) => async dispatch => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };

    const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });

    try {
        const res = await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/jwt/create/`, body, config);

        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data
        });

        dispatch(load_user());
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_FAIL
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When i do user authentication, and i want to conditially render a component. I use React routing dom. This way i can create a PrivateRoute that will render the individual component out and redirect if the user !isAuthenticated. Check this out /

https://blog.bitsrc.io/build-a-login-auth-app-with-mern-stack-part-1-c405048e3669

This is the tutorial that you can [clone](https://github.com/rishipr/mern-auth/) the git

**Private Route:**

```js
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, auth, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      auth.isAuthenticated === true ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/login" />
      )
    }
  />
);

PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

**MAIN APP:**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import setAuthToken from "./utils/setAuthToken";

import { setCurrentUser, logoutUser } from "./actions/authActions";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./store";

import Navbar from "./components/layout/Navbar";
import Landing from "./components/layout/Landing";
import Register from "./components/auth/Register";
import Login from "./components/auth/Login";
import PrivateRoute from "./components/private-route/PrivateRoute";
import Dashboard from "./components/dashboard/Dashboard";

import "./App.css";

// Check for token to keep user logged in
if (localStorage.jwtToken) {
  // Set auth token header auth
  const token = localStorage.jwtToken;
  setAuthToken(token);
  // Decode token and get user info and exp
  const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
  // Set user and isAuthenticated
  store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
  // Check for expired token
  const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000; // to get in milliseconds
  if (decoded.exp < currentTime) {
    // Logout user
    store.dispatch(logoutUser());

    // Redirect to login
    window.location.href = "./login";
  }
}
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <div className="App">
            <Navbar />
            <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
            <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Switch>
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks, I´m already doing the redirect based on the authentication but I was thinking about rendering for example a success message for the user if the login was successful. So when the dispatch `LOGIN_SUCCESS` gets send the Message Component should be shown.